# Preserving attributes without value when manipulating with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The crux of my problem comes down to this issue:

```
$('<video allowfullscreen></video>').prop('outerHTML') === '<video allowfullscreen></video>' //Is False
$('<video allowfullscreen></video>').prop('outerHTML') === '<video allowfullscreen=""></video>' //Is True
```

The input I'm giving to jQuery gets partially mangled and transformed in an unwanted way.

My goal is that I have (trusted) html coming in that I want to modify by adding some attributes and wrapping it in other elements before converting it back to a String and passing it to the user as text they can copy.
So an expected output might be something like:

```
<div><video class="myClass" allowfullscreen></video></div>
```

Since the input html is coming from elsewhere I'd like to make as little assumptions about it as possible. So ideally I don't want to take the string and parse over it to fix specific attributes or remove instances of ="" (in case there's a reason at some point to specifically set a property to "").

Even if I don't care about having a value set on these properties the correct value would be `allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"` anyways. I don't have control over the html coming in so I need to take it as-is. So I can't simply 'fix' the html to pass along something like `allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"`.

Are there any options or ways to preserve valueless properties when I go from string->jQuery->string?

I'm even open to other technology suggestions that would be better suited to this sort of DOM manipulation, but jQuery would otherwise be ideal because of how concise its syntax is. Vanilla Javascript can do it properly, but the syntax makes the code more brittle which I would like to avoid.

Comment: _"The input I'm giving to jQuery gets partially mangled and transformed in an unwanted way."_ Not certain issue is `jQuery` related ? , but `DOCTYPE` `namespace` , `html5` related ?

Answer (score 0):

See [HTML5 - 8.1.2.3 Attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#attributes-0)

> 8.1.2.3 Attributes
>
> Attributes for an element are expressed inside the element's start
>   tag.
>
> Attributes have a name and a value. Attribute names must consist of
>   one or more characters other than the space characters, U+0000 NULL,
>   U+0022 QUOTATION MARK ("), U+0027 APOSTROPHE ('), ">" (U+003E), "/"
>   (U+002F), and "=" (U+003D) characters, the control characters, and any
>   characters that are not defined by Unicode. In the HTML syntax,
>   attribute names, even those for foreign elements, may be written with
>   any mix of lower- and uppercase letters that are an ASCII
>   case-insensitive match for the attribute's name.
>
> Attribute values are a mixture of text and character references,
>   except with the additional restriction that the text cannot contain an
>   ambiguous ampersand.
>
> Attributes can be specified in four different ways:
>
> **Empty attribute syntax**
>
> **Just the attribute name. The value is implicitly the empty string.**

Comment: The issue here is the code goes out to people that are less technical where they may not know that allowfullscreen="" is allowing fullscreen. We want to avoid the issue where people may fiddle with the html themselves and try things like allowfullscreen="false". Plus it just looks cleaner for users.

Comment: _"The issue here is the code goes out to people that are less technical where they may not know that allowfullscreen="" is allowing fullscreen."_ Include `comment` with `html` that is sent with above link , or portion of description in bold at Answer ?